# debugging is not working, but just running is fine on PyCharm 2.7

Tags: debugging, pycharm

If I run the program, it outputs the results fine, but if I try to debug it, I get the following error:

```
...
ï»¿# coding=utf-8
     ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

I have

```
# encoding=utf-8
```

on the first line. This is not a syntatic error, because even if I delete the first line, I get the same error message with `ï»¿` prepended to the new first line.

I have set the EOL to be LF and the encoding to be UTF-8. My PyCharm is updated to the latest version 129.782

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened up gVim and removed those characters. For some reason it would not appear in PyCharm. I am almost certain that PyCharm put that there though. I cannot type those characters with my keyboard, and I do not work with such characters for my programs.

Comment: Those "characters" are UTF-8 BOM header: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark